# Accessing the contents of a function from a struct defined inside that function

Tags: c++

```
typedef void (*voidfunc)();

void somefunc(voidfunc function)
{
    voidfunc func = function;
    struct wrapper
    {
        function(); //does not work
        func(); //does not work
    };
}
```

Is there any way at all to access `function` from inside the struct `wrapper`? I am trying to see if it is possible to implement python style wrapper. Something like a timer. Where `somefunc` takes a function, `wrapper` runs that function and timers it.

Something like this ?

```
wrapper_struct_type timer(voidfunc function)
{
    struct wrapper
    {
        void timeit()
        {
            //start time
            function(); //does not work
            //endtime
            //time = end- start
        }
    };

    //return wrapper
}
```

Working example in python

```
import time

def timer(func):
    def wrapper():
        start = time.time()
        func()
        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)

    return wrapper

@timer
def somefunc():
    print("hello world")

 
somefunc()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You can't make function calls like that at class-scope.

Comment: @cigen I was trying to see if it is possible to implement python style wrappers

Comment: Oh, I'm not really sure what those are. You should definitely add relevant information like that to the question, preferably with some working python code for which you're trying to write the python equivalent.

Comment: I may be wrong, but don't you have to dereference the function pointers before calling them?

Comment: @DanteCulaciati No, they are automatically dereferenced.

Comment: Put a member of voidfunc type (or voidfunc reference type) inside a wrapper struct and initialize it in the struct's constructor, that would allow accessing it from inside of the struct's methods scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Lambda Solution

You can achieve this using [C++ lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Note my example requires C++14 (or greater) to compile.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*voidfunc)();

void doNothing() {}

auto foo(voidfunc function)
{
    auto wrapper = [function]()
    {
        int x = 1;
        function();
        int y = 1;
        std::cout << y - x << "\n";
    };

    return wrapper;
}

int main()
{
    auto fn = foo(doNothing);
    fn();
    foo(doNothing)();
    return 0;
}
```

In the `foo` function, the `function` passed to `foo` is ["captured"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) for use in the lambda's body. Then, the function is executed in the body of the lambda. At the end of the body of `foo`, the lambda is returned.

Then the `main` function demonstrates how the `foo` function can be used. A `voidfunc` can be passed to `foo`, and then the returned lambda can be assigned to a variable (in my example it is assigned to `fn`). Then the returned lambda can be invoked (in my example it is invoked with `fn()`). Or, the returned lambda can be invoked directly, without using a variable (in my example I do this with `foo(doNothing)();`).

I use `int x` and `int y` as examples since I do not know what precision you might be looking for for time deltas.

#### Lambda-free Solution

Here is an alternate (and, in my opinion, less elegant) solution that works if lambdas are not supported for the C++ compiler/standard you are compiling with:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*voidfunc)();

struct Foo
{
    voidfunc function;

    Foo(voidfunc fn) : function(fn) {}

    void wrapper()
    {
        int x = 1;
        function();
        int y = 1;
        std::cout << y - x << "\n";
    }
};

void doNothing() {}

int main()
{
    Foo foo(doNothing);
    foo.wrapper();
    return 0;
}
```

Here, there is a `Foo` struct that is passed a `voidfunc` function via its constructor. The `voidfunc` is then stored as the `function` member of the `Foo` `struct` (`function` could be declared as `private` if desired).

In `main` in my example, a `Foo` is created as `foo`. Then, whenever the `wrapper` function is executed on `foo`, the function stored in `foo` will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a struct and overload the [call operator](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/1830/function-call-operator). The struct will take a `std::function<void()>` in its constructor. Then simply call the instance of the struct.

[`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) gives you type erasure. So as long you have any callable that has the right signature, it will provide a wrapper around it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

struct timerit
{
    timerit(std::function<void()> fn) : mFunction{fn} {}

    void operator()() const
    {
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start =  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        mFunction();
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end =  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto dur = end - start;
        auto milli = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(dur);
        std::cout << milli.count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    }

    std::function<void()> mFunction;
};

void count()
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i);
}

int main()
{
    auto lambda = []() { for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i); };

    timerit t1{lambda};  //lambda
    t1();

    timerit t2{count};   //function
    t2();

    return 0;
}
```

Live [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YMbYqM)

Note that you also do this:

```
timerit{lambda}();
```

which will invoke the call operator immediately without giving you an variable of type `timerit`.

You can provide your own implementation inside the call operator and call the function object that you pass in. My implementation sticks closely to the timer example that you provided in your question.